# Looping using FOR in batch (*.bat) / CMD

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

i have batch script (*.bat). i use windows 7. i want to learn how to use FOR syntax to looping

```
echo off 
:bulan 
cls 
echo. 
echo. 
set /P start= Input start : %=% 
set /P end= Input End : %=% 
set mount1=%start% 
set mount2=%end% 
set i=1

for /L %%i IN (%mount1%,1,%mount2%) DO echo Hello %i% !!! 
set i=%%i%+1 
pause
```

Result :

```
Input start : 1 
Input End : 5 
Hello 1 !!! 
Hello 1 !!! 
Hello 1 !!! 
Hello 1 !!! 
Hello 1 !!!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How to make result like this

```
Input start : 1 
Input End : 5 
Hello 1 !!! 
Hello 2 !!! 
Hello 3 !!! 
Hello 4 !!! 
Hello 5 !!!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /L %%i IN (%mount1%,1,%mount2%) DO echo Hello %%i !!!
```

remove this: `set i=%%i%+1`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /l %%a in (1,1,%counter%) do echo Hello...
```

Comment: `for /l %%a in (1,1,%counter%) do echo Hello %%a` You again missed a, `%%a`. Whats up with your coffeemachine? ^^

Comment: Thank for your answer. but iam sorry, i have edit my question

Comment: do not enhance questions, it's against thr SO rules. Simply make new ones.

Comment: @Stephan thank you, but see the question _before_ the edit by OP.

Comment: @Endoro I will not repeat again. please, forgive me

Comment: You should not use `%i%` but `%%i`.