# Using wget to get an excel files with FOR loop syntax on batch/CMD (*.bat) programing

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Refer to My question [Looping using FOR in batch (*.bat) / CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181768/looping-using-for-in-batch-bat-cmd).

I want to use wget to get an excel files.

```
excel01.xls --> link : http://portal/excel01.xls
excel02.xls --> link : http://portal/excel02.xls
...
excel12.xls --> link : http://portal/excel12.xls
```

My code :

```
echo off
set /P start= Input start : %=%
set /P end= Input End : %=%

for /l %%i IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO echo wget "http://portal/excel0%%i.xls"
pause
```

Result :

```
Input start : 1
Input End : 12
wget "http://portal/excel01.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel02.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel03.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel04.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel05.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel06.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel07.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel08.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel09.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel010.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel011.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel012.xls"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

how the correct script that results in row 10-12 :

```
wget "http://portal/excel010.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel011.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel012.xls"
```

become

```
wget "http://portal/excel10.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel11.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel12.xls"
```

I'm sorry I do not speak English very well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script prepends a `0` to the number, then gets the last two characters. I have assumed you don't need to worry about numbers >= 100.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /P start= Input start : %=%
set /P end= Input End : %=%

for /l %%i IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO (
    set num=0%%i
    set num=!num:~-2!
    echo wget "http://portal/excel!num!.xls"
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother. work for me. Can you explain this line **set num=!num:~-2!** ??

Comment: i takes the last two characters of !num! (see `set /?`)